# Prestashop 1.7 disable payment

Tags: php, payment, prestashop-1.7

I did many search on web to disable payment on PrestaShop.
My customer want a website with orders but no payment (payment is make offline with an ERP software)

Anybody has an idea to do this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without a heavy core modification.

The quickest workaround is to leave only one payment module active (like cash on delivery that doesn't actual require a real payment) and translate it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I know this but I wanted to know if there is a "cleaner" way to achieve what I want.
I do not wish to modify the core so I will opt for this solution.

Thank you